# How does Lubuntu manage a full battery?

Tags: 14.04, lubuntu, battery, macbook

I installed Lubuntu 14.04 on my white MacBook 13''. Originally when running Mac OS X on a fully powered battery, while plugged to the AC, it would completely bypass the battery and run on the AC only. This was indicated by the magsafe light turning green. Does Lubuntu have the same powering behavior? As seen below the battery status says "Adapter is online", indicating it is using the AC I assume, but yet it says the battery is charging and the magsafe light is still red, indicating charging. In order to preserve the battery charge as long as possible should I take out the battery when using the AC, or does Lubuntu indeed bypass the battery as well?

[image]

Okay while typing the light just turned green (it's the first time using my new battery on Lubuntu), but the question remains. Is my battery bypassed to preserve its charge?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know, Lubuntu uses AC power while the cable is plugged in and the battery fully charged. You can change your power settings using xfce power manager 4 which is installed by default and can be found under

Menu>Preferences>Power Manager